# Need to drop all connections from IPVS

Tags: networking, tcp, connection

I have a Directing Routing IPVS which I am putting through some tests. For accuracy, I need to be able to drop all of the active and inactive connections before I begin testing.

The inactive TCP connection timeout is fairly long, but I'm not allowed to change it. Does anyone know a method I can use to close all of the existing connections?

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown the ethernet interface in linux